# jQuery slider doesn't work in Safari desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

i have created a jquery carousel, which has only a next/prev functionality, everything is working fine in Chrome whereas there are problems in safari. Thus the images that should be hidden in the slider are appearing at the bottom (visually hidden, i have checked with firebug).
This happens only in Safari.

```
<div class="slider">
    <a class="prev-arrow arrow"></a>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1Icor0I" class="active">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1Ubvzly">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1KDjkg6">
            <img alt="" src="http://smu.gs/1IwVgJp">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1JV31pa">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1eFfcNZ">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1DdSEjq">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1SQshBK">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1LUnGxU">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1fO17ic">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1ha0UHb">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1IOce80">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1gsBwwf">
            <img alt="" src="http://bit.ly/1LUnHBZ">
        </div>
    <a class="next-arrow arrow"></a>
</div>


$(document).on("click", ".prev-arrow", function () {
      var imageContainer = $(this).next();
      imageContainer.animate({"scrollLeft":imageContainer.scrollLeft() - 300}, 200);
});

$(document).on("click", ".next-arrow", function () {
     var imageContainer = $(this).prev();
     imageContainer.animate({"scrollLeft":imageContainer.scrollLeft() + 300}, 200);
});
```

and css

```
.slider .image-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:500px;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-left: 25px;
    height: 120px;
}

.slider .image-container img {
    display: inline-block;
    width:200px;
        margin-left: 2px;
}

.slider .image-container img.active {
    border: 6px solid #007aff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.slider {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
}

.prev-arrow {
    width: 13px;
    height: 23px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url("/images/agency/left-arrow.jpg");
    background-color:red;
}

.next-arrow {
    width: 13px;
    height: 23px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url("/images/agency/right-arrow.jpg");
    background-color:red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zzLf1pL3/
I don't want to make many changes my HTML code. Because it will make me to re-write a  lot of other stuff.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Safari does not supprt scrollLeft now

Comment: @Farhan thanks for reply, is there any alternative for it?

Comment: searched a lot to ans you but didn't find any suitable answer. let me search again :)